# Knockout.js dropdown bind selected

Tags: knockout.js

Having problem with binding the initial selection for the dropdown, all will be fine if specify "optionValue", but if have this specified, then after selection changed, it will only return the value instead of the entire object, which is what I want, return the entire object, like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/Princa/tuMta/109/

So how should I bind an initial value without specify 'optionValue'? I set the

```
selectedCountry: ko.observable(new Country("Sweden", 29000000)),
```

but it didn't work

Comment: updated my answer, that fiddles works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `optionValue` setting is only for the "placeholder" value that is displayed in the select list when no item is selected.

If you want actually default the selection to an item in the list, do this in your view model itself by setting the `selectedCountry` variable to a valid value.

Example from your jsfiddle  (updated here:  http://jsfiddle.net/tuMta/110/):

```
viewModel.selectedCountry(viewModel.availableCountries()[1]);
```

Comment: Awesome! I didn't realize that the two objects are not "identical". where could I find this kind of documents?!

Comment: That's a good question....not sure where is the best place to point you...this article may help explain it:  http://stamat.wordpress.com/2013/06/22/javascript-object-comparison/.  In general, objects are considered to be equal only if they occupy the same location in memory.  So two objects created independently will always be separate objects, even if they contain the same contents.

Comment: Think of it this way, if you create two separate `Country` objects and modify the name of one, the other is not modified.  This indicates that they are distinct objects.

Comment: yes, I do know about that they are not the same objects, but I am not aware that the dropdown is expecting the exactly object to match. Usually i think we just match selected value, which is value type, but for object, which is reference type maybe different handled in KO.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that even the 2 clases you created are sweden, js does not know that, so you have to let it know it. try this way:

```
var viewModel = function () { 
var defaultSelected = new Country("Sweden", 29000000);
this.availableCountries = ko.observableArray([
    new Country("UK", 65000000),
    new Country("USA", 320000000),
    defaultSelected]);
this.selectedCountry= ko.observable(defaultSelected); 
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tuMta/120/

Comment: @JosephGabriel my bad, the real problem is that there are 2 diferent objects, new conty('sweden') is diferent to new country('sweden'). Ill update